# What's the difference between Apps on Facebook and Apps on Pages?

Tags: facebook

I'm learning the Platform Policies, I'm confused at "a. Apps on Pages must not host media that plays automatically without a user's interaction.". What is the difference between the two terms "Apps on Facebook" & "Apps on Pages". Can I add an intro movie which plays automatically when someone accesses my Facebook app?

Answer (score 0):

Apps on Facebook are Canvas apps (760px+ wide) where as Page apps are loaded on the actual Facebook page with a width of 520px.

Canvas:

https://apps.facebook.com/lemsipmanflu/

Page tab:

https://www.facebook.com/SonyPlaystation?sk=app_222589261140674